# I've received an export 'network error' in attempt to export a database from phpMyAdmin

Tags: database, drupal-7, backup

When I tried to export a test database as SQL, it gave me a network error file. When I retry the download, it renames the document to index.html.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF4nd.png)

[Renamed HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syWq0.png)

When I open that .html file, it reads:

index.php: Missing parameter: what

index.php: Missing parameter: export_type

[Error Message From HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yydcG.png)

Thoughts? I am Novice but I can follow direction.

I followed directions that I found online re: backing up my database; I'm trying to create backups for a staged environment. I hope to be able to transition the database into a live environment in the future.

This is a personal project; I'm trying to create and educational database for neurodiagnostics. I have prior experience with HTML, CSS, and drupal but I do not effectively know my way around PHP. If there is a better way for me to backup a local database then I would be happy to learn how to do so.